# Do I have to bring both passports to enter India with an eTourist visa?

Tags: visas, passports, india, canadian-citizens

On the eTourist visa to india, should I really have to specify both my passports (Canada and the US)? If yes, do I have to bring both passports to enter or just one?

Comment: @pnuts I'm applying as a Canadian citizen

Answer (score 1):

Declare both nationalities, but enter India on the one the entry permit is linked to.

Thus, you only Need to bring both passports in case your trip starts, ends or goes through the US